# How to redirect from a child class to the parent class#show view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have an application where an Event has_many Videos, which belongs_to an Event.  How can I click on an instance of the video and have it redirect to the events#show view using it's event_id foreign key to identify the correct event?  The association definitely works, but I'm struggling to think through the logic, or even where the redirect should take place i.e. in the routes, the controller or the view?

Here's some code which may be relevant:

From the view

```
 <% @video.each do |v| %>
   <li><%= link_to image_tag(v.video_thumb('150'), width: 150), v %></li>
<% end %>


class VideosController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @video = Video.find(params[:id])
    if current_event
      @videos = current_event.videos
      @random_video = current_event.videos.random
    else
      @videos = Video.all
      @random_video = Video.random
    end
  end


class EventsController < ApplicationController
def show
    @event = Event.find_by_name(request.subdomain)
    if request.params[:id].present?
      @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    end

    if not @event.nil? and @event.videos.any?
      @video = Video.random(@event)
      @comment = @video.comments.new
      @comments = @video.comments
    end
  end

  resources :events do
    match '', to: 'events#show', constraints: lambda { |r| r.subdomain.present? && r.subdomain != 'www' }
  end
resources :videos
```

Let me know if there is any other code you might need to help and I will update the question with the relevant code.

Thanks for any help....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use event_path(@event.video)

Let me tell you that, when a video belongs to event, you can easily find the association event related to that video will be easily found from that object. For example:

```
@video = Video.find(params[:id])
@event = @video.event
```

for link generation simply: link_to @event.name, event_path(@event)

// if there is any subdomain for that event and if subdomain define the 
EventsController#show as root then to go to that event show page we can write:

```
link_to "#{@video.event.name}", root_url(:subdomain => 
@video.event.name)
```

or same:

```
link_to "#{@event.name}", root_url(:subdomain => @event.name
```

I hope this will work!